# Android UI display differently in graphical layout and AVD

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I try to make a rouned EditText.It display well in the Graphical layout in main.xml. But it is still square when i launch the AVD.Here is the code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:hint="Enter a #hashtag or keyword"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/magnifier"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:textSize="16dp" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText> 
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
```

Comment: post your rounded_edittextxml also.

Comment: sorry to forget to add the rouneded_edittext.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a rounded edit text that change also behavour on clik states, Simply use thes xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_states.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
     android:state_pressed="true" 
     android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_focused" />
    <item 
     android:state_focused="true" 
     android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_focused" />
    <item 
     android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
</selector>
```

Normal rounded edittext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Pressed,Focused edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_focused.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
 <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

And... now, the EditText should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
    android:padding="5dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i used this layout to test it for and it works for me even with multiple  round edittext:

this is the layout i use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:hint="Enter a Login"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter a Password"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is a screen capture of the result on emulator:

[image]

Comment: this is what the OP did. what changes you did ?

Comment: can you tell me what the OP want to do?

Comment: @Padma Kumar: sorry if you feel that im copying the OP is question, you are right but i was thinking that he had missed something that he had not mention!! so i tried to help him with an already working solution that i know.
testing his code on my emulator and my device worked also!! he have no mistakes in his code but i can't figure why he get a rectangular edittext on his emulator even if his code worked for me on both avd and real device.

Comment: Sorry guys, it still doesnt work. I thought it worked when i added another EditText below the previous one. The newly added edittext is rounded. But when I delete the top one, the below one moves top and becomes square.

Comment: +1 - this is how answers should be! Thorough, with well formatted code and helpful screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

// I feel that your rounded_edittext.xml is wrong.

can you remove this 2 lines

```
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle"
```

//Or you can use myshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#FAFFFA"/>    

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>

 <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#C3C3C3"/> 

</shape>
```

Comment: I think the code i posted is right. I did a test that I created two EditText, one is on top of another. I make both of them rounded, but the code only works for the below one. When I delete the top Edittext, the code doesnt work for the left one. Do you have any idea of this situation?

Comment: I didnt get your question. how you are deleting do u mean that visibiliy=gone?

Comment: I mean I created two EditView for test. Only the below one is rounded. Then I delete the top one, so the below one moves top and become the only one left in the main.xml. When there are two EditText, the below one is round and the top one is squre. when there is only one EditText, it is square. It is so strange. Maybe the location has something to do with this situation?

Comment: it's working for me even for multiples edittext!! see updated answer